# Install black with pipx not install dependencies aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pipx

On MacOs I've installed with brew the pipx:

`brew install pipx`

then `pipx install black`

```
$ pipx list                                           
venvs are in /Users/mc/.local/pipx/venvs
apps are exposed on your $PATH at /Users/mc/.local/bin
   package black 22.12.0, installed using Python 3.11.1
    - black
    - blackd
```

However, I keep getting missing dependency:

```
$ /Users/mc/.local/bin/blackd                         
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mc/.local/bin/blackd", line 5, in <module>
    from blackd import patched_main
  File "/Users/mc/.local/pipx/venvs/black/lib/python3.11/site-packages/blackd/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: aiohttp dependency is not installed: No module named 'aiohttp'. Please re-install black with the '[d]' extra install to obtain aiohttp_cors: `pip install black[d]`
```

1. How to fix it?
2. Why `pipx` is not solving this dependency while installing `black` ?
3. Why it uses some (no idea where is this installed) python `3.11.1` when my system python is `3.9.6`

   $ python3 --version
   Python 3.9.6

EDIT

I've did as advised by below answer from @KarlKnechtel :

```
$ brew install python@3.10                                
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (romkatv/powerlevel10k).

You have 2 outdated formulae installed.
You can upgrade them with brew upgrade
or list them with brew outdated.

==> Fetching python@3.10
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/python/3.10/manifests/3.10.9
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/python/3.10/blobs/sha256:a9b28161cec6e1a027f1eab7576af7
==> Downloading from https://pkg-containers.githubusercontent.com/ghcr1/blobs/sha256:a9b28161cec6e1a027f
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring python@3.10--3.10.9.arm64_monterey.bottle.tar.gz
==> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/bin/python3.10 -m ensurepip
==> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/bin/python3.10 -m pip install -v --no-deps --no-index --upgr
==> Caveats
Python has been installed as
  /opt/homebrew/bin/python3

Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
`python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
  /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/libexec/bin

You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>
They will install into the site-package directory
  /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages

tkinter is no longer included with this formula, but it is available separately:
  brew install python-tk@3.10

See: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python
==> Summary
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9: 3,110 files, 57.1MB
==> Running `brew cleanup python@3.10`...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
```

so I got:

```
$ python3 --version                                      
Python 3.10.9

$brew list python python3
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/bin/2to3
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/bin/2to3-3.10
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/bin/idle3
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/bin/idle3.10
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/bin/pip3
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/bin/pip3.10
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/bin/pydoc3
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/bin/pydoc3.10
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/bin/python3
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/bin/python3-config
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/bin/python3.10
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/bin/python3.10-config
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/bin/wheel3
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/bin/wheel3.10
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/ (3055 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/IDLE 3.app/Contents/ (8 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/lib/pkgconfig/ (4 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/libexec/bin/ (6 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/libexec/wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Python Launcher 3.app/Contents/ (16 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/share/man/ (2 files)
```

but still when I install `black` it installs python `3.11`:

```
$pipx install black[d]                                   
zsh: no matches found: black[d]

$pipx install black                                    
  installed package black 22.12.0, installed using Python 3.11.1
  These apps are now globally available
    - black
    - blackd
done! ✨  ✨
```

Comment: Do you see the part of the error message that says "Please re-install black with the '[d]' extra install to obtain aiohttp_cors: `pip install black[d]`"? Did you try that? What happened when you tried that?

Comment: "Why it uses some (no idea where is this installed) python 3.11.1" It's installed in the virtual environment that `pipx` is using, which is seen in the error message: `/Users/mc/.local/pipx/venvs/black/lib/python3.11`. If you would [read the documentation](https://pypa.github.io/pipx/), or even the [project readme on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pipx/) for pipx, you would see that the *entire purpose* of `pipx` is to have an isolated environment for what you install, i.e. **not** the system Python.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel i want to install blackd with `pipx` not with `pip`. And it sounds it is installed. So shall I reinstall with `pipx` ? What diffeerence would it make?

Comment: The point is the `[d]` on the install line. `pipx` should use the same syntax that `pip` does.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel So I've tried as you've advised in the answer and it turns out that pipx can't find `blackd` I've editet the question and added the procedure in my question below the EDIT mark. It still uses 3.11.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it as in edit 1 but later you have to do according to [this](https://github.com/pypa/pipx/issues/46):

```
pipx install "black[d]" --force
```

but after that I got error:

```
dyld[56881]: Library not loaded: '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Python'
  Referenced from: '/Users/mc/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/bin/python'
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Python' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Python' (no such file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Python' (no such file)
```

so I had to:

```
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - --uninstall
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
```

And now:

```
poetry env use /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/bin/python3.10
```

as 3.10 is required for `aiohttp` as mentioned by @KarlKnechel

Answer (score 1):

When you use `pipx` rather than `pip` to install a package, it will:

- **create a new virtual environment** for the package
- use `pip` to install the package into that virtual environment
- Do some additional setup work, so that "entry points" for the package (commands created by the package to use directly at the command line, such as `blackd`) will work, without having to activate the specific virtual environment first.

That is its **explicit purpose** (i.e., the reason not to just use `pip`), and therefore why there is a different Python being used rather than the system Python.

To use the `blackd` entry point defined by Black (which starts up a server), the `aiohttp` optional dependency is required. This must be specified at installation. Per the error message, with `pip`, this looks like `pip install black[d]`.

However, from the Black release notes (since version 22.8.0; current version 22.12.0):

> Python 3.11 is now supported, except for *blackd* as aiohttp does not support 3.11 as of publishing (#3234)

So, `pipx` will need to use an older version to create the virtual environment.

From [the `pipx` documentation](https://pypa.github.io/pipx/docs/):

> The default python executable used to install a package is
> typically the python used to execute pipx and can be overridden
> by setting the environment variable `PIPX_DEFAULT_PYTHON`.

Presumably, `brew install pipx` installed `pipx` into some 3.11 install that is not the system Python. This sort of thing happens because **you are not intended to install anything into the system Python**. As the name suggests, your (operating) system depends on it, and a rogue package could seriously harm your computer in any number of ways. (Hence why `pip` is not available in it by default.)

You can:

- use `brew` to install 3.10 or earlier, then install `pipx` to that, then proceed with `pipx install black[d]`.
- use `venv` to create a virtual environment based off your system Python (3.9); this `venv` should include `pip` automatically by default (downloaded and installed by `venv`). Activate this virtual environment, then use `pip` to install `pipx` in it, then proceed with `pipx install black[d]`.

Comment: This should be accepted answer: explains everything the OP stumbled on and more +1